# Google API: convert auth_code to access_token | Python

Tags: python, oauth, token

I'm trying to convert an auth_code provided from client to a token on my backend. (front and back are two different serves).

> `scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
>       code='code=4/nQCEBlo_YbWfOw1NXCWJ3UCyRzPT*****NJbda0eaXdmv032qX2PZhV4Cd2YzO3sPQ36*************'
>       # Exchange auth code for access token, refresh token, and ID token
>       c = client.credentials_from_code('***ClientID*****-*****************.apps.googleusercontent.com'
>                                        ,'SECRET*********',scope,code)
>       print (c.id_token)`

another try was:

```
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    'code=4/nQCEBlo_YbWfOw1NXC****************4Cd2Y*********mGgA')
```

I received this error:

```
    raise FlowExchangeError(error_msg)
oauth2client.client.FlowExchangeError: invalid_grantMalformed auth code.
```

any idea?
**Thanks!**

Comment: It's Saying the request that you are making to the Google Auth Server is wrongly formed. Can you show the Sample implementation what you are doing?

Comment: I’m trying to send the auth code to google servers for token convertion I’m not sure about the implementation or the syntax do you have example? Thanks

Comment: They have already shown the implementation in their guides. Are you following that?
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: This is not my case.
the client open browser using server 1 receiving the auth_code, then calling server 2 which receives this code and need to covert it to a token. Then server2 will perform some actions using that token.  I don't understand exactly how to use the conversion function - that is my issue here.